# most readable way in XPath to write "is value X a member of sequence S"?

Tags: coding-style, xpath-2.0

XPath 2.0 has some new functions and syntax, relative to 1.0, that work with sequences. Some of theset don't really add to what the language could already do in 1.0 (with node sets), but they make it easier to express the desired logic in ways that are more readable. This increases the chances of the programmer getting the code correct -- and keeping it that way. For example,

- [`empty(s)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-empty) is equivalent to `not(s)`, but its intent is much clearer when you want to test whether a sequence is empty.

  - **Correction**: the [effective boolean value](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-ebv) of a sequence is in general more complicated than that. E.g. `empty((0))` != `not((0))`. This applies to `exists(s)` vs. `s` in a boolean context as well. However, there are domains of `s` where `empty(s)` is equivalent to `not(s)`, so the two could be used interchangeably within those domains. But this goes to show that the use of `empty()` can make a non-trivial difference in making code easier to understand.
- Similarly, [`exists(s)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-exists) is equivalent to `boolean(s)` that already existed in XPath 1.0 (or just `s` in a boolean context), but again is much clearer about the intent.
- [Quantified expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-quantified-expressions); e.g. "`some $x in` *expression* `satisfies` *test*`($x)`" would be equivalent to `boolean(`*expression*`[`*test*`(.)])` (although the new syntax is more flexible, in that you don't need to worry about losing the context item because you have the variable to refer to it by).
- Similarly, "`every $x in` *expression* `satisfies` *test*`($x)`" would be equivalent to `not(`*expression*`[not(`*test*`(.))])` but is more readable.

These functions and syntax were evidently added at no small cost, solely to serve the goal of writing XPath that is easier to map to how humans think. This implies, as experienced developers know, that understandable code is significantly superior to code that is difficult to understand.

Given all that ... what would be a clear and readable way to write an XPath test expression that asks

> Does value X occur in sequence S?

Some ways to do it: (Note: I used `X` and `S` notation here to indicate the value and the sequence, but I don't mean to imply that these subexpressions are element name tests, nor that they are simple expressions. They could be complicated.)

1. `X = S`: This would be one of the most unreadable, since it requires the reader to

   - think about which of X and S are sequences vs. single values
   - understand general comparisons, which are not obvious from the syntax

     1. However, one advantage of this form is that it allows us to put the [topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic%E2%80%93comment) (X) before the *comment* ("is a member of S"), which, I think, helps in readability.
     2. See also [CMS's good point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17253884/423105) about readability, when the syntax or names make the "cardinality" of X and S obvious.
2. `index-of(S, X)`: This one is clear about what's intended as a value and what as a sequence (if you remember the order of arguments to `index-of()`). But it expresses more than we need to: it asks for the index, when all we really want to know is *whether* X occurs in S. This is somewhat misleading to the reader. An experienced developer will figure out what's intended, with some effort and with understanding of the context. But the more we rely on context to understand the intent of each line, the more understanding the code becomes a circular (spiral) and potentially [Sisyphean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus) task! Also, since `index-of()` is designed to return a list of all the indexes of occurrences of X, it could be more expensive than necessary: a smart processor, in order to evaluate `X = S`, wouldn't necessarily have to find all the contents of S, nor enumerate them in order; but for `index-of(S, X)`, correct order would have to be determined, and all contents of S must be compared to X. One other drawback of using `index-of()` is that it's limited to using `eq` for comparison; you can't, for example, use it to ask whether a node is *identical* to any node in a given sequence.

   - **Correction:** This form, used as a conditional test, can result in a runtime error: `Effective boolean value is not defined for a sequence of two or more items starting with a numeric value`. (But at least we won't get *wrong* boolean values, since `index-of()` can't return a zero.) If S can have multiple instances of X, this is another good reason to prefer form 3 or 6.
3. `exists(index-of(X, S))`: makes the intent clearer, and would help the processor eliminate the performance penalty if the processor is smart enough.
4. `some $m in S satisfies $m eq X`: This one is very clear, and matches our intent exactly. It seems long-winded compared to 1, and that in itself can reduce readability. But maybe that's an acceptable price for clarity. Keep in mind that X and S could potentially be complex expressions themselves -- they're not necessarily just variable references. An advantage is that since the `eq` operator is explicit, you can replace it with `is` or any other comparison operator.
5. `S[. eq X]`: clearer than 1, but shares the semantic drawbacks of 2: it computes all members of S that are equal to X. Actually, this could return a false negative (incorrect effective boolean value), if X is falsy. E.g. `(0, 1)[. eq 0]` returns 0 which is falsy, even though `0` occurs in `(0, 1)`.
6. `exists(S[. eq X])`: Clearer than 1, 2, 3, and 5. Not as clear as 4, but shorter. Avoids the drawbacks of 5 (or at least most of them, depending on the processor smarts).

I'm kind of leaning toward the last one, at this point: `exists(S[. eq X])`

What about you... As a developer coming to a complex, unfamiliar XSLT or XQuery or other program that uses XPath 2.0, and wanting to figure out what that program is doing, which would you find easiest to read?

Apologies for the long question. Thanks for reading this far.

**Edit:** I changed `=` to `eq` wherever possible in the above discussion, to make it easier to see where a "value comparison" (as opposed to a general comparison) was intended.

Comment: Lest someone think I'm against the use of existential comparisons ... I'm not. I use them frequently, for short or routine tasks. But today I have a long XPath expression that isn't working the way I expect, and I can't figure out why. So I'm breaking everything down to make it as clear as possible. P.S. @DimitreNovatchev I'd like to hear your perspective on this. :-)

Comment: If possible, I would use the [functx](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_is-node-in-sequence.html) library for XQuery or XSLT;  the code is then a fairly readable `functx:is-node-in-sequence($X, $Y)`

Comment: @evilotto: Thanks... I hadn't heard of that library. So we can use it in XSLT, even though it's written in XQuery?

Comment: There's an XSLT version also - http://www.xsltfunctions.com/  (both linked from http://www.functx.com/)

Comment: @evil: I'd like to have this as an answer so that I can upvote it and so that others can easily find it.

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, if names or context make clear that X is a singleton, I'm happy to use your first form, X = S -- for example when I want to check an attribute value against a set of possible values:

```
<xsl:when test="@type = ('A', 'A+', 'A-', 'B+')" />
```

or

```
<xsl:when test="@type = $magic-types"/>
```

If I think there is a risk of confusion, then I like your sixth formulation.  The less frequently I have to remember the rules for calculating an effective boolean value, the less frequently I make a mistake with them.

Answer (score 2):

**I prefer this one**:

```
count(distinct-values($seq)) eq count(distinct-values(($x, $seq)))
```

**When $x is itself a sequence, this expression implements the (value-based) *subset of* relation between two sets of values**, that are represented as sequences. This implementation of *subset of* has just linear time complexity -- vs many other ways of expressing this, that have O(N^2)) time complexity.

**To summarize**, the question whether a *single* value belongs to a set of values is a special case of the question whether one *set* of values is a subset of another. If we have a good implementation of the latter, we can simply use it for answering the former.

Comment: Thanks, Dimitre. I'm curious, why does `distinct-values()` have linear time complexity? I would expect it to be O(n^2). I guess if it's implemented with a hashtable...

Comment: @LarsH, ANy hash-table based implementation gives us this efficient implementation. A binary search tree implementation is also efficient O(N*log(N)) ),  but not as efficient as the hashtable-based one. Can you notice a similarity with a wellknown node-set subset test? :)

Comment: I suspect you're referring to the `count($nodeset) = count($nodeset | $x)` of XPath 1.0. :-) Yeah, that and the above work well, but I can't say I find them  highly readable. For XPath 1.0 there was little choice, but I don't know why we'd want to use this in 2.0, other than nostalgia. I see your point about efficiency for the *subset-of* relation, but for the *member-of* relation there are more readable expressions that are also O(N).

Comment: @LarsH, In fact, for the "member-of" relation there is an O(1) implementation -- if the *hasn-set* corresponding to `distinct-values($seq)` has already been calculated. A good optimizer would do this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with *hasn-set* (or is it hash set?) Can you elaborate?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26268/discussion-between-larsh-and-dimitre-novatchev)

Comment: It is HashSet<T> and is a standard .NET class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx

Comment: Speaking about efficiency, very few people know that there is a very efficient implementation of substring -- and the same algorithm can be adapted for sub-sequence (not subset).

Answer (score 2):

The [functx library](http://functx.com) has a nice implementation of this function, so you can use

```
functx:is-node-in-sequence($X, $Y)
```

(this particular function can be found at http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_is-node-in-sequence.html)

The whole functx library is available for both XQuery (http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/) and XSLT  (http://www.xsltfunctions.com/)

Marklogic ships the functx library with their core product; other vendors may also.

Comment: evil otto, Lars wants to test the membership of *any item* -- not only a node -- to a sequence. The cited function doesn't do that -- it is limited to membership of a node to a sequence of nodes.

Comment: There is also `functx:is-value-in-sequence()` - the essence of my suggestion is that functx provides nicely-named versions of many such functions.

Comment: Yes, Lars was asking about the second function. It might be useful if you could edit the answer and replace the function with `is-value-in-sequence()`. Anyway, I see that the implementation is quite inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, when you want to know whether **node** X occurs in sequence S, is

```
exists((X) intersect S)
```

I think that's pretty readable, and concise. But it only works when X and the values in S are *nodes*; if you try to ask

```
exists(('bob') intersect ('alice', 'bob'))
```

you'll get a runtime error.
In the program I'm working on now, I need to compare strings, so this isn't an option.

As Dimitri notes, the occurrence of a node in a sequence is a question of identity, not of value comparison.

Comment: Lars, There is an important difference: This uses identity-based equality -- not value-based equality. Both are useful, but quite different.

Comment: @Dimitre: good point; and isn't it true that identity relations in XPath apply only to nodes? I.e. there is no other data type for which identity-based equality has any meaning. You could ask whether strings `$a` and `$b` have the same type and the same string value, but cannot ask whether they are the same string object.

Comment: Lars, exactly. "value types" have value-based equality. "Reference types" have identity-based equality.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: I would have said that reference types (like nodes) can also have value-based equality, as in `X = S`. But maybe it's more accurate to say that if you take the *value* of a node (e.g. the implicit `string(X)` in `X = S`) that you can do value-based equality.

Comment: [I would have said that reference types (like nodes) can also have value-based equality]. Only if one views nodes as containers, and nothing more. Nodes that are "value-equal" in general aren't "identity-equal" and can have very different important properties -- such as parent, preceding and following nodes, document node, etc.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: Sure. But value-based comparison of nodes (viewing them merely as containers, for a given purpose) is a common and useful operation, as long as the user understands what is actually being compared. That's why XPath has had the powerful general comparison `=` operator for node-sets since 1.0.

Comment: Sure, but in case one is designing a *general* capability such as Saxon's saxon:memo-function="yes", then the only *safe* implementation is using identity-based equality for nodes. Of course, if an additional attribute is used saying: "node-equality='value-based'" then it would be possible to implement both types of equality.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: Agreed that if you're designing a general capability where the spec just says "the same arguments", then you're only safe if you interpret that as strictly as possible.